# Artemis : Slave will be live as per the configured time (in millisecond)

Tags: activemq-artemis

Current implementation of master/slave is if master goes down the slave will start immediately. I am looking for option to run slave (Backup server as live) as per the given time if master goes down

Comment: What's your use-case for needing a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't support any delay for the activation of the slave when its master goes down.